# Laravel Auth::user() relationships

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get my users role relation through the Auth::user() function. I have done this before but for some reason it is not working.

```
Auth::user()->role
```

This returns the error trying to get property from non-object.

In my user model I have this:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('vendor\package\Models\Role');
}
```

In my role model I have:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('vendor\package\Models\User');
    }
```

When I do this it returns the name of my role, so my relations are correct I think:

```
User::whereEmail('test@test.be')->first()->role->name
```

What am I missing?

Comment: are you sure that Auth::user() returns an Eloquent Model?

Comment: Yes `Auth::user()` returns eloquent instance of User model (when found).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I found out why it wasn't working for me.
The thing is that my User model where I was talking about was a part of my package, and because Laravel has it's own User model in the default Laravel installation it was not working.

Your package model does not override an already existing model. I solved my problem by making a Trait instead of a model for my package.

Answer (score 4):

`Auth::user` can return a non-object when no user is logged in. You can use `Auth::check()` to guard against this, or even `Auth::user` itself:

```
if(!($user = Auth::user())) {
    // No user logged in
} else {
    $role = $user->role;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
if(Auth::check()) {
    $role = Auth::user()->role;
}
```

Comment: or simply rely on middleware! and not checking needed. There is one that L5 is shipping out with. **app/Http/middleware/Authenticate.php** and registered as "auth" in **app/Http/kernel.php**.

Comment: That's correct, and a great point. OP didn't specify what version of Laravel he's on, though, so I assumed Laravel 4.

Comment: I assumed L5 :) but either way if L4 there are filters for that.

Comment: For all we know this code is running inside of a filter, OP makes no distinction in his question.

Comment: Sorry that I was not clear enough, the version of Laravel that I am using for this project is 4.2 and the code that I'm trying to run is located in a filter 'role' This filter is executed after the auth filter so my user is definitely logged in to my application. Auth::user() returns my user by the way.

Comment: @JorenVanHocht does the same thing happen if you split it up? ie `$user = Auth::user(); $role = $user->role` Or if you use the query builder? `$user = Auth::user(); `$role = $user->role()->first()` ? (sorry, I somehow missed your earlier comment)

Comment: When I split it up it also returns null. When I do $role = $user->role()->first() I get Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::role().

The strange thing is that it works without Auth::user() by just selecting a user by it's email, like said in my first post.