# Laravel receive information from user

Tags: laravel-5

I've got two tables: a user table and a car table. When a user is logged in I want to show his cars, with lots of information. But how do I do this in the controller, including giving the right car information from that user? I have already set the relations but how do I receive the right information in the controller?

I was thinking about this:

```
$car = car()->user();
        return view('cars.index',compact('usercar','car'));
```

Of course this is wrong, but what's the right way?

EDIT:

This is my controller and this is the index method:

```
use App\Car;
public function index()
    {
        $car = Auth::user()->Car;
        return view('tickets.index',compact('usercar','car'));
    }
```

This is my user model:

```
use App\Car;
    public function car()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Car');
}
```

This is my car model:

```
use App\User;
    public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And this is my route:

```
Route::get('/tickets','TicketsController@index');
```

> in Model.php line 893 at FatalErrorException->__construct() in
>   HandleExceptions.php line 133 at
>   HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php
>   line 118 at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php
>   line 0 at Model->hasMany() in User.php line 39 at
>   User->rittenregistratie() in Model.php line 2658 at
>   Model->getRelationshipFromMethod() in Model.php line 2631 at
>   Model->getRelationValue() in Model.php line 2573 at
>   Model->getAttribute() in Model.php line 3291 at Model->__get() in
>   Controller.php line 30

EDIT:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;
class Car extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Car';
    protected $fillable = ['beginstand', 'eindstand', 'van','naar','bezoekadres','geredenroute','karakterrit','toelichting','kilomterszakelijk','kilomtersprive'];

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your relations are correct you should be able to do this:

```
$cars = Auth::user()->cars; // cars being the name of the relation method
return view('cars.index', compact('cars'));
```

Since you said *"show his cars"* I'm guessing one user can have many cars, so expect `$cars` to be a collection and not a single model.

Comment: thanks again for your reply :) but I receive the error: FatalErrorException in Model.php line 893:
Class 'app\cars' not found. The namespace etc. is correct.

Comment: Sounds like your relationship is wrong. Should be `$this->hasMany('App\Car');` (or whatever your class is named)

Comment: The relations are correct. I"ve now idea why I receive the FatalErrorException because I've namspaced it and also put the use etc. at the top.

Comment: Then please edit your question and show me your code. Otherwise I can't help you any further.

Comment: Please, please use capitalized namespaces and classnames!

Comment: I've edit that. Also I've put more error code in my edit.

Comment: Are both models namespaced? (with `namespace App;`)

Comment: yes I've made them with php artisan, so that's done automatically.

Comment: Yes but when I do $car = car::all() it works, so the class is found. But when I do $car = Auth::user()->car; it throws that error? (and I'm logged in!)

Comment: Could you try this in your controller please? `$car = app('App\Car');`

Comment: When I only put that in my controller it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: That's very strange. Because the model uses the same underlying method to create the model instance for the relation...
It might help if you copy pasted your full model code into the question.

Comment: Found the problem! When I did composer dump-autoload it worked!

Comment: Are you sure that are you logged in? Use the Auth::check() method inside an if to verify that the user is realy logged in: if (Auth::check()) { //do al the crap}, then check this answer, maybe your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990995/laravel-authuser-relationships

Comment: @jamie Glad to hear that